# Using Rust to execute FFMPEG commands

Tags: audio, rust, input, ffmpeg, command

I am using rust to envoke some an ffmpeg command to record desktop audio, microphone audio, and desktop video. I type the command in the CMD and it works, here is that command.
`ffmpeg -hide_banner -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Arctis Nova Pro Wireless)" -f dshow -i audio="What U Hear (Sound Blaster Audigy 5/Rx)" -filter_complex amix=inputs=2 -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -show_region 1 -video_size 600x600 -offset_x 10 -offset_y 20 -i desktop -strftime 1 -y "out%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4"`

And this is the command object with all the arguments

```
let mut ffmpegcommand = Command::new("ffmpeg");
    ffmpegcommand.arg("-hide_banner")
    .arg("-y")
    .arg("-f")
    .arg("dshow")
    .arg("-i")
    .arg("audio=\"Microphone (Arctis Nova Pro Wireless)\"") 
    .arg("-f")
    .arg("dshow")
    .arg("-i")
    .arg("audio=\"What U Hear (Sound Blaster Audigy 5/Rx)\"")
    .arg("-filter_complex")
    .arg("amix=inputs=2")
    .arg("-f")
    .arg("gdigrab")
    .arg("-framerate")
    .arg("60")
    .arg("-show_region")
    .arg("1")
    .arg("-video_size")
    .arg("600x600")
    .arg("-offset_x")
    .arg("100")
    .arg("-offset_y")
    .arg("100")
    .arg("-i")
    .arg("desktop")
    .arg("-strftime")
    .arg("1")
    .arg("G:\\School\\Capstone\\screenshotFFMPEG\\%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4");
    ffmpegcommand.status().expect("DID NTO WORK LOSER");
```

Envoking this command results in this error from the console:

```
[dshow @ 0000026421be4880] Could not find audio only device with name ["Microphone (Arctis Nova Pro Wireless)"] among source devices of type audio.
[dshow @ 0000026421be4880] Searching for audio device within video devices for "Microphone (Arctis Nova Pro Wireless)"
[dshow @ 0000026421be4880] Could not find audio only device with name ["Microphone (Arctis Nova Pro Wireless)"] among source devices of type video.
audio="Microphone (Arctis Nova Pro Wireless)": I/O error
```

I would think that the error is the device name is wrong being that they NEED to have the "'s when ffmpeg gets it but I am lost because in the error the name is perfectly identical with the output for the device when I do a ffmpeg -list_devices command

```
[dshow @ 0000013ea9cfe600] "Microphone (Arctis Nova Pro Wireless)" (audio)
[dshow @ 0000013ea9cfe600]   Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{DE99F572-E285-4EBC-A263-2D782B212FA7}"
```

There are no spaces and to my knowledge the names are identical. I am at a loss, any assistance is appriciated.

Comment: I must note that I already tried the alternative unique device name and got the same error. I am using the a json file to put values into the arguments but trying to break down this issue I am just passing strings for the time being.

Answer (score 2):

I tried with the quotes (with my microphone name) and got the same error, so I removed the quotes and it worked fine. Which means the quotes are substituted by the shell instead of ffmpeg.

```rs
.arg("audio=Microphone (Arctis Nova Pro Wireless)")
```

Note that since each argument is already separated into strings, you don't need the quotes to pass arguments with spaces. Also note you can use `args` to pass many arguments.

```rs
.args([
    "-hide_banner",
    "-y",
    "-f",
    "dshow",
    "-i",
    "audio=Microphone (Arctis Nova Pro Wireless)",
    "-f",
    "dshow",
    "-i",
    "audio=What U Hear (Sound Blaster Audigy 5/Rx)",
    "-filter_complex",
    "amix=inputs=2",
    "-f",
    "gdigrab",
    "-framerate",
    "60",
    "-show_region",
    "1",
    "-video_size",
    "600x600",
    "-offset_x",
    "100",
    "-offset_y",
    "100",
    "-i",
    "desktop",
    "-strftime",
    "1",
    "G:\\School\\Capstone\\screenshotFFMPEG\\%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.mp4",
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My arguments work now, I really appriciate it. I did not anticipate the shell to be giving me problems.